# How do you disable a button after 5 seconds (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm not very familiar with discord.js buttons and need help disabling a button after 5 seconds to avoid spam but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```js
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#2ACAEA')
  .setTitle("Commands")
  .setDescription("Page 1 of 2")
  .addFields(
    {name: '!jn help', value: 'This command'},
    {name: '!jn ping', value: 'Ping the bot.'},
    {name: '!jn coinflip', value: 'Flip a coin :D'},
    {name: '!jn amiadmin', value: 'Are you an admin? We can see!'}
  )
  .setFooter('Need more help? Join the support discord server.')
  .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/Ta0yst7.png');

const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new Discord.MessageButton()
      .setCustomId('2')
      .setLabel('>>')
      .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
  );

message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row]});

setTimeout(function () {
  row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
}, 5000);
```

When I try, it doesn't output any errors. I think I'm just missing something.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Try placing this below row.components[0].setDisabled(true):
 `message.edit({embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row]})`

Comment: @Dregg
`DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track - you've done the first step, which is to change the button to be disabled after 5 seconds *locally*, but now you need to edit your message to reflect those changes online.

First, you have to store your sent message in a variable:

```js
const sentMessage = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
```

Then, in your `setTimeout`, you can edit the `sentMessage` like Dregg said in his comment:

```js
// After you disable the button
sentMessage.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
```

Comment: Thank for the help! I was thinking I needed to store the message.